# How to publish 400mb size apk to playstore exported from unity in android studio?

Tags: android, android-studio, unity-game-engine, arcore

Iam using Google ARCore sdk to develop AR Android application with 30 3d models using unity.I was exported android project from unity and import into android studio and build application it was run perfectly.But the apk size is 400mb in that case i can't upload my application because playstore apk size restriction is 100mb.I was also set split into binary into unity and build it but the apk size is same 400mb.How can i publish my app to playstore?

Comment: there is no way to publish 400 mb single APK. You have to split it into 2 parts - 1) main apk, and 2) expansion file

Comment: i was split the binary in unity but the apk size is same 400mb the expansion file size is 192 bytes.

Comment: then you have probably misplaced your 3d models, so they are treated a a part of main APK, not a part of expansion.

Comment: I was placed 3d models into assets folder only.

Comment: any other location to place models?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/272165/6296561

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you have to add an additional slim first scene which does not need many models and thus can stay below 100MB.

The rest of the scenes (i.e. your main ARCore scene) should then be transferred to the expansion file as explained [here](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/android-OBBsupport.html).

Comment: I have game object in ARCore Scene that contain 30 preflabs.that is the reason apk size is increased?

Comment: If i create a slim first scene how ARCore Scene will Display?

Comment: You can change the scene to display using [Application.LoadLevel](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Application.LoadLevel.html)

Comment: Can i use Application.LoadLevel in update method in C# script?

Comment: Thank you for your answer.I added the first scene with cupe In the cupe script Update method i was navigate the ARCore scene.apk size was reduced and obb splitted properly.is i was done correctly what you said?